# Ubuntu 18.04 python 2.7 urllib request not getting data

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, urllib, ubuntu-18.04

I have this python script which works with no problem on ubuntu 16.04
But it wont get data in ubuntu 18.04, any idea what the problem could be?
No errors.

```
    try:
        exchrate=float(json.loads(requests.get("http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json").read())['bpi'][currency]['rate_float'])
        print exchrate
    except:
            try:
                print("Can not get data from coindesk.com")
                print("Trying to get data from coinbase.com")
                exchrate=float(json.loads(urllib2.urlopen("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=BTC").read())["data"]["rates"][currency])
                print exchrate
            except:
                try:
                    print("Can not get data from coinbase.com")
                    print("Trying to get data from blockchain.info")
                    exchrate=float(json.loads(urllib2.urlopen("https://blockchain.info/ticker").read())[currency]["last"])
                    print exchrate
                except:
                    print("Can not get data from blockchain.info")
                    print("Failed to get BTC exchange rate")
                    sys.exit()
```

Output:

```
Can not get data from coindesk.com
Trying to get data from coinbase.com
Can not get data from coinbase.com
Trying to get data from blockchain.info
Can not get data from blockchain.info
Failed to get BTC exchange rate
```

Full code is here : https://github.com/papampi/nvOC_by_fullzero_Community_Release/blob/Dual-cuda/WTM_SWITCHER

Comment: currency is read from cfg file, its usually USD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the Requests library, you should use it on each API. Requests provides a method to extract JSON, so you don't need to call the `json` module yourself.

When multiple things can go wrong, it's not a good idea to bundle them all together in one line. Do them in stages so you can see exactly where the error occurred, and deal it with it appropriately. Also, using unnamed `except` blocks is rarely a good idea: you might catch something that you don't know how to handle.

Here's a re-organized version of your code.

```
import requests

currency = "USD"

apis = [
    {
        "name": "coindesk.com",
        "url": "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json",
        "keys": ("bpi", currency, "rate_float"),
    },
    {
        "name": "coinbase.com",
        "url": "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=BTC",
        "keys": ("data", "rates", currency),
    },
    {
        "name": "blockchain.info",
        "url": "https://blockchain.info/ticker",
        "keys": (currency, "last"),
    },
]

for d in apis:
    name, url, keys = d["name"], d["url"], d["keys"]
    print("Trying", name)
    try:
        req = requests.get(url)
        req.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)
        print("Cannot get data from", name)
        continue

    try:
        # Extract the exchange rate
        data = req.json()
        for k in keys:
            data = data[k]
    except KeyError as e:
        print("Bad key!:", e)
        continue

    try:
        # Convert the exchange rate to a float.
        # Some APIs return it as a float, but coinbase.com returns
        # a string. This code also handles None, which in JSON is null
        # If you just want to print the rate, this conversion is not needed.
        rate = float(data) 
        print("Rate", rate)
        break
    except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
        print("Invalid exchange rate data", data, type(data))
else:
    print("Failed to get BTC exchange rate")
```

**typical output**

```
Trying coindesk.com
Rate 6440.64
```

**Update:** I've improved the error-handling of this code.

Comment: Thanks. it looks nice, but give some errors when a link is not responding.

Comment: @papampi It should print an error message if a link doesn't respond and then try the next URL. If you don't want to see that error message, just delete or comment-out the `print(e)` line. But I recommend printing info like that while you're still working on the script. It's almost always better to have some superfluous debugging info than not enough debugging info. I spent a few minutes testing this code (eg, with malformed URLs), but you should probably do more extensive tests to make sure that it can handle all possible error conditions.

Comment: It just exits on some errors, for example try a broken link like: 1api.coindesk.com instead of api.coindesk.com ...

Comment: @papampi That's weird. On my system it doesn't "just exit" on that bad URL, it prints a whole bunch of Exception messages. Anyway, I've fixed that by using the generic Requests exception that all Requests exceptions inherit from. I've also added some error handling that should cope with any bad exchange rate data.

Comment: I meant other than the errors, it just exist instead of trying other urls

Comment: Later in my code I have :
`exchrateLog = open(outputDir + "/WTM_BTC_EXCHANGE_RATE", "w")
exchrateLog.write(str(rate) + " " + str(currency))`

How do I read from it if all the above link checks failed?

Comment: @papampi Ah, right. It confused me because you didn't mention the errors. And I was on my phone, so I couldn't test it myself.

Comment: @papampi You can open and read the old data in the `else` section where we print "Failed to get BTC exchange rate". And then I guess the program should exit, since you probably don't want to write that old data back to the log file.

Comment: This is how it became:
https://github.com/papampi/nvOC_by_fullzero_Community_Release/blob/Dual-cuda/WTM_SWITCHER

Comment: @papampi That's cool, but when you use other people's code verbatim you should give them attribution (mention their name). The bottom of every Stack Overflow page says "user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with attribution required". At a minimum, that means you're supposed to mention the code author's name, and Stack Overflow. Please see [Attribution Required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) and [legal](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) for further details.

Comment: Done. Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 2):

Requests is able to [parse the JSON for you](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content). Try this:

```
response = requests.get("http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
rate_float = response.json()['bpi']["USD"]['rate_float']
print(rate_float)
```

Output:

```
6366.6563
```

**Edit:**

> No errors...

You silently swallow any error thrown. That's a bad idea, especially when you try to debug. Don't do this:

```
try:
    this_breaks()
except:
    try_other_thing()
```

You will never know **why** `this_breaks()` broke exactly. Either don't use `try/except` and let the exception appear, or at least print it:

```
try:
    this_breaks()
except Error as e:
    print("error: ", e)
    try_other_thing()
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions